# Redirect from old indexed pages with url rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have some old indexed pages in Google that need to be redirected to their new locations. Example: Google shows `wwww.domain.com/pages/subpages/page.php` that is now in `www.domain.com/pages/page.php`.

I also need, when someone clicks on the old page in Google, to open rewritten URL.
Example: User clicks on `wwww.domain.com/pages/subpages/page.php`, it will open him `wwww.domain.com/pages/page.php`, but with `www.domain.com/page` in address bar (without "pages/" and php extension).

So I have written this .htaccess code

```
Redirect 301 /pages/subpages/page.php http://www.domain.com/page
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^page/?$ /pages/page.php
```

The redirect works, but user have in address bar full URL (`http://www.domain.com/pages/page.php`), not the rewritten one(`http://www.domain.com/page`). It looks like the mod_rewrite doesn't work with redirect or something.

Is there any solution?

Comment: 1) Can you ensure that mod_rewrite is actually enabled? If you visit `www.domain.com/page`, does it show you the page ..or gives an error? 2) Do you have any other redirect/rewrite rules somewhere else (another .htaccess file in `/pages/` subfolder etc)?

Comment: yes, mod_rewrite is enabled. it does work when i access page by typing this address to browser http://www.domain.com/page. it just doesn't work after redirect.

Comment: 2) no, i dont have any other. just this .htaccess in root folder i have provided

Answer (score 1):

This code works fine for me:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# 301 redirect
RewriteRule ^pages/subpages/page\.php$ http://www.domain.com/page [R=301,L]

# rewrite
RewriteRule ^page/?$ /pages/page.php [L]
```

Please ensure that you have no other redirects/rewrites in your htaccess file as they may may perform additional rewrite/redirect actions.

Comment: when I put this in htaccess, it crashes the whole page with Internal server error

Comment: Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, root@nameserver.sk and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Comment: @Radovan What do you mean by _"the error log is not available yet"_. If it is available then it should be accessible (at least I have not seen any other behaviour in this regards). Nevertheless try removing `Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews` and/or `RewriteBase /` and see if it makes any difference. These rules are correct and should work fine (they do on my box).

Comment: for some reason log files are generated every dat at 4:00AM, so i don't have it yet

Comment: @Radovan That most likely means that there is no separate error log for your site -- most likely there is 1 log for all sites/whole server .. or something like that. Oh well -- you have to wait then. In mean time you may contact you hosting company and they may give you some explanation/advice on what is going on and how to solve it -- it may be quicker.

Comment: it looks like this line is critical Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews. when i delete it, it works but still not corectly.

Comment: @Radovan It is possible that `+FollowSymLinks` cannot be used there. Try `+SymLinksIfOwnerMatch` instead. This htaccess is working fine for me (I tested before posting). Try temporarily removing all other .htaccess in all folders along `/pages/subpages/` path (if any) and make this .htaccess as short as possible (just these rules). Also -- make another `page.php` -- and make it pretty much empty (no framework/project code) -- maybe that final redirect is done from within PHP code ...

Comment: Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch causes also 500 internal error :( As I said, I have no other htaccess files, just the one in the root folder. BTW is it possible that the htaccess is cached? I have just removed the whole content and add a redirect to an empty file as you suggested but it wasn't reacting to any change and the old redirect was still working.

Comment: @Radovan Yes, it is possible to configure Apache to check for changes in htaccess not on every request, but once a minute or even less frequently.

Comment: it's working .. my browser was caching old htaccess file. after cleaning caches everything is ok.

Comment: @Radovan Your browser CANNOT cache .htaccess file (as it is server side only), but it can cache redirects (especially 301 ones).